# Consolidating keys in dictionary based on items in corresponding value lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with arbitrary key names and values that are lists corresponding to nodes in those keys:

```
{'foo': ["1", "2", "7"], 'bar': ["4", "8", "7"], 'baz': ["5", "6"]}
```

I need to consolidate this dictionary such that if ANY of the items in the list are in another list, the two lists combine into one key:

Desired Output:

```
{'foo': ["1", "2", "4", "7", "7", "8"], 'baz': ["5", "6"]}
```

I currently have the following code, but at the scale of the dictionary it will take far too long to run:

```
def consolidate(orig_dict):
    consolidated = {}
    removed = set()

    for key, val in orig_dict.items():
        if key in removed:
            continue
        consolidated.setdefault(key, val)

        for item in val:
            for key2, val2 in orig_dict.items():
                if key == key2:
                    continue
                if key2 in removed:
                    continue
                if item in val2:
                    val.extend(val2)
                    removed.add(key)
                    removed.add(key2)

     return consolidated
```

I am specifically looking any way to lessen time complexity, and am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop is going through ALL the keys again. You don't need to check the preceding keys again, so you should keep track of the key position (with `enumerate`) and only check the following elements. Beside you can make a set from `val` to increase speed of membership testing:

```
def consolidate(orig_dict):
    consolidated = dict()
    removed = set()
    for i, (key, val) in enumerate(orig_dict.items()):
        if key in removed:
            continue
        consolidated.setdefault(key, val)
        val_set = set(val)
        for key2, val2 in [(k,v) for k,v in list(orig_dict.items())[i+1:] if k not in removed]:
            if any(item in val_set for item in val2):
                consolidated[key] += val2
                removed.add(key2)

    return consolidated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets and set intersections to speed up the operations.

```
a = {'foo': ["1", "2", "7"], 'bar': ["4", "8", "7"], 'baz': ["5", "6"]}
consolidated = {}
joined_keys = set()
for k1, v1 in a.items():
  if k1 in joined_keys:
    continue
  joined_keys.add(k1)
  set_v1 = set(v1)
  
  for k2, v2 in a.items():
    if k2 not in joined_keys and set(v2) & set_v1:
      v1.extend(v2)
      joined_keys.add(k2)
  consolidated[k1]=v1
print(consolidated)
```

Comment: `set(v2) & set_v1` is actually **slower** than `any(item in val_set for item in val2)` since `any` will stop as soon as one match is found.